# Kafka consumer groups still exists after the zookeeper and Kafka servers are restarted

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm using Zookeeper and Kafka for messaging use case using Java. I thought consumer group details will be removed when you restart Zookeeper and Kafka servers. But they don't. Does zookeeper keeps consumer groups details in some kind of a file?

Should I remove consumer group details manually if I want to reset the consumer groups?

Can anyone clarify this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Kafka 0.9, Consumer Offsets are stored directly in Kafka in an internal topic called `__consumer_offsets`.

Consumer Offsets are preserved across restarts and are kept at least for `offsets.retention.minutes` (7 days by default).

If you want to reset a Consumer Group, you can:

- use the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool with the `--reset-offsets` option
- use [AdminClient.deleteConsumerGroups()](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#deleteConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-) to fully delete the Consumer group